# SQL Server 2008 express r2

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008

I installed SQL server 2008 r2 on Windows server 2008 and its working fine but it takes to much memory. So I decided to install sql server 2008 r2 express. I tried it couple times and all the time Im getting error after a while of installing 'User doesn't have permissions ..'
I tried two times and its showing me two partially installed sql server instances.

I have 3 questions:
How to uninstall those two sql server express instances?
How to install properly sql server express instance?
 - Which user account I need to specify for running sqlserver instance?

Thank you for detailed answer

Answer (score 1):

> How to uninstall those two sql server
>   express instances?

Log in as admin, uninstall. Never had to (normally you dont uninstall sql server). Like any other program. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909967 has some information that is still relevant for 2008.

> How to install properly sql server
>   express instance?

Log in as local admin, start installer.

> Which user account I need to specify
>   for running sqlserver instance?

Depends on waht you WANT. I normally run them as local system or aspecial domain user, depending on security needs.

> I installed SQL server 2008 r2 on
>   Windows server 2008 and its working
>   fine but it takes to much memory.

I bet it does NOT take too much memory (i.e. more memor than it should). SQL Server likes using all memory as cache because it assumes it is alone on the computer - which is a VERY valid assumption. Should this be false, thre are properties in teh server you can set that limit the memory use. So, per definition "too much memory" is more memory than the machine has (causing swapping) or you ahve defined. I really bet this is not the case.

Comment: Where I can find settings to configure memory usage?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remove the instances using Add/Remove Programs. You'll need administrative rights to do the install, the permissions on the service account will depend on whether it needs access to domain resources, there is more info [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504.aspx)

As for the memory consumption of the Standard edition, the default behavior of SQL assumes it can use as much memory as it wants, but you can easily limit it through a configuration option.